# display a UIViewController in a container

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIViewController. In this UIViewcontroller ist a container. In this container is a Tab Bar Controller. One of the Tabs is a PageViewController embed in a Navigation Controller. One of the Pages is UITableViewController.

```
UIViewController->Container->TabBarController->NavigationController->PageViewController->UITableViewController
```

If you click on one of the Cells I want to display a UIViewContoller. But this UIViewcontroller should be only in the container and in the NavigationController. If I click on a Cell you can see for 0.3 sec the right result. With a "back" button at the navigation bar. But then the UIViewController switch to full size.

I display the UIViewController as follows:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("article")
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I get the following Waring:

```
Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <Test.AllArticlesTableViewController: 0x7f812bd227d0>.
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: What is self in the context above? The last `UITableViewController`? maybe try `self.navigationController.presentViewController` instead. I think `UIPageViewController` technically adds view controllers dynamically so when you present from it you get that warning since it's a "detached" `UIViewController` in the `UIPageViewController`

Comment: You are right. I dont get the error message with (self.navigationController!.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)). But the ViewController is still in fullscreen mode! How I make this ViewController a part of the NavigationController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presenting a view controller will take up the full screen by default. I believe what you're looking for is to push the view controller onto the navigation stack. Use `pushViewController(_:animated:)`.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
self.navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

> "***Pushing*** a view controller causes its view to be embedded in the navigation interface."

Please refer to the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/pushViewController:animated:) for more information.

Comment: hey , thats nice. I tryed "self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)" and now the UIViewControler is displayed right. But now something strange happen: It load the UIViewController two times. And I have to click 2 times on "back" to get back to my UIViewTableController. The animation, when it present the viewController, is also 2 times. So its UITableViewController -> myUiViewController -> myUiViewController.

Comment: Can you post your method which has your code in it so I can take a look? Also please check you are not presenting/pushing the view controller from anywhere else e.g.. Storyboards etc

Comment: Hey I found the mistake, I connected the cell with the UIViewController in the storyboard. Thank you very much!